# Multiplying Transposed Matrix with a Second Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, transpose

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int m, n, p, q, c, d, k, sum = 0;
  int first[10][10], transpose [20] [20], second[10][10], multiply[10][10];

  // m row n col of first matrix
  // transpose would be m col n row of first matrix 



  printf("Enter number of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  printf("Enter elements of first matrix\n");

  for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
      scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);

 //make first matrix transpose 

     for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j) {
            transpose[d][c] = first[c][d]; //c becomes column d is row
        }



  printf("Enter number of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);

  if (m != p)
    printf("The multiplication isn't possible.\n");
  else
  {
    printf("Enter elements of second matrix\n");

    for (c = 0; c < p; c++)
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++) {
        for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
          sum = sum + transpose[d][k]*second[k][d];
        }

        multiply[d][c] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }

    printf("Product of the matrices:\n");

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
      for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        printf("%d\t", multiply[d][c]);

      printf("\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My goal is to take transpose of first matrix and then multiply it with a second matrix. I found sample codes and edit them as i needed and it seems to be working until multiplication part. It gives me unrelated numbers such as in the picture below. Also i need to add if else to somepart of this code so that if column value is not equal to row value, program should stop executing.
[image]

Comment: After the comment `//make first matrix transpose`, you've got nested loops using `i` and `j` as the loop variables, but using `c` and `d` as the indexes into the matrix.

Comment: i changed it to transpose[i][j] = first[j][i]; however now it gives me a result that is transposed of the expected result. okay i also changed to printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]); and now everything seems to be working just fine. Thank you so much!